# Share files with "New Outlook" from UWP apps

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, sharing, uwp

Is there a way to enable the "New Outlook" to show up in the regular file sharing dialog used by Windows 11 (23H2) or is this possibility not provided by Microsoft at all? By default, it will just show the "old" Outlook:

[image: Sharing dialog of UWP in Windows 11]

I tried to find some system settings on this but was not successful.

Comment: Another missing option with New Outlook? We have many posts here about New Outlook, where the only real solution is to avoid using it (if the problem is serious enough).

Comment: I agree, just a customer request  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There is no way, New Outlook does not support it. Still have to switch back to the classic version.